# Rename a PostgreSQL table to contain the current timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql

please help, i want to change the name of the existing table by adding current_date , example trans_table20210723

i have tried using query

```
DO $$ 
BEGIN 
  EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %I RENAME TO %I_%s', 'DETAILDATABT','DETAILDATABT', to_char(current_date,'YYYYMMDD')::TEXT); 
END $$;
```

but still not working

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of repeating the variable or using `concat`, use its position in the parameters list, e.g. `1$` to get the first parameter:

```
DO $$ 
BEGIN 
  EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %1$s RENAME TO %1$s_%2$s',
    'DETAILDATABT',to_char(current_date,'YYYYMMDD')); 
END $$;
```

Demo:

```
db=# CREATE TABLE DETAILDATABT (id int);
CREATE TABLE

db=# DO $$                    
BEGIN 
  EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %1$s RENAME TO %1$s_%2$s',
'DETAILDATABT',to_char(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYYMMDD')); 
END $$;
DO

db=# \d detaildatabt_20210723 
       Table "public.detaildatabt_20210723"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 id     | integer |           |          |
```

Comment: Note  that this will fail with table names that require quoting (which is handled by the `%I` placeholder)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I totally agree. Your solution is undoubtedly the best one / more complete one and should be accepted. However, a downvote seems perhaps a little bit harsh to something that clearly works given the OP scenario.  As a fan of your answers, If you see it differently I gladly take the critic and delete my post :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the concatenated values as the value for a **single** `%I` parameter and get rid of the `%s` part:

```
DO $$ 
BEGIN 
  EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %I RENAME TO %I', 
                 'DETAILDATABT', 
                 concat('DETAILDATABT', '_', to_char(current_date,'YYYYMMDD')); 
END $$;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, after I tried with a little change

DO $$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE schema.%I RENAME TO %I', 'detaildatabt',
                  concat('detaildatabt', '_', to_char(current_date,'YYYYMMDD')));
END $$;

it works